# How can I make an arrow returning to same entry in xymatrix?

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

I'm trying to make a diagram with arrows returning to the same entry using `xymatrix`. The following example works perfectly fine.

```
\[
\xymatrix{
V \ar@(dl,ul)[]^{h'} \ar@<0.5ex>[r]^{i} & W \ar@(dr,ur)[]_{h} \ar@<0.5ex>[l]^{p} 
},
\]
```

However, if I try to change `V` to `(V,d_V)`, I only get error messages. 
I tried already to place it into `{}`, but it makes no difference. Typing

```
\[
\xymatrix{
{(V,d_V)} \ar@(dl,ul)[]^{h'} \ar@<0.5ex>[r]^{i} & {(W,d_W)} \ar@(dr,ur)[]_{h} \ar@<0.5ex>[l]^{p} 
},
\]
```

I still get error messages like

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\splineendScan@ ...s@ \expandafter {\splineedges@ 
                                              }\xylowtolerance@ \splined...
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: This may be a defect of xy-pic, you can change V to (x,y) but not (X,Y), and for (x,y) the result is unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xy-pic sometimes has problems with curving or turning arrows when the nodes are too large.  (I've never been able to predict when the problems would arise.)  For a crude workaround, you can use

```
\[
\xymatrix{
  *[r]{\;(V,d_V)\;} \ar@<0.5ex>[rr]^{i} \ar@(dl,ul)[]^{h'} 
  && *[l]{\;(W,d_W)\,} \ar@<0.5ex>[ll]^{p} \ar@(dr,ur)[]_{h} 
},
\]
```

We used `*[r]{node}` to shift that first node to the right and `*[l]{node}` to shift that second node to the left.  We also padded each node with a `\;` at the beginning and end, and we made the second node *two* jumps to the right, and made the arrows into `\ar[rr]` and `\ar[ll]`, to leave room for the arrows (which were otherwise crowded by the shifted nodes).  It's crude, but it mostly works:
[image]